# NodeJS: Return statics mongoose undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can I return the following as a function I can use over and over:

```
pageSchema.statics.getData = function(d) {
    this.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { 'order' : -1 } }, function(err, page) {
        return page[d];
    });
};
```

This gives me undefined.

And I want to use my function as this. Where I get the page property order.

```
Page.getData('order');
```

Which chould be a single number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return an asynchronous result from a synchronous function.  Your function needs to have a callback parameter to provide the result back to the caller.

```
pageSchema.statics.getData = function(d, callback) {
    this.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { 'order' : -1 } }, function(err, page) {
        callback(page[d]);
    });
};

Page.getData('order', function(data) { ... });
```

Comment: Alright thanks for the answer :) I'm just fiddling around with it, to see what I can do.